# Combine a compile-time integer type with a dynamic type

Tags: rust, typenum

I am using `typenum` in Rust to add compile-time dimension checking to some types I am working with. I would like to combine it with a dynamic type so that an expression with mismatched dimensions would fail at compile time if given two incompatible `typenum` types, but compile fine and fail at runtime if one or more of the types is `Dynamic`. Is this possible in Rust? If so, how would I combine Unsigned and Dynamic?

```
extern crate typenum;
use typenum::Unsigned;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Dynamic {}

// N needs to be some kind of union type of Unsigned and Dynamic, but don't know how
struct Vector<E, N: Unsigned> {
    vec: Vec<E>,
    _marker: PhantomData<(N)>,
}

impl<E, N: Unsigned> Vector<E, N> {
    fn new(vec: Vec<E>) -> Self {
        assert!(N::to_usize() == vec.len());
        Vector {
            vec: vec,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

fn add<E, N: Unsigned>(vector1: &Vector<E, N>, vector2: &Vector<E, N>) {
    print!("Implement addition here")
}

fn main() {
    use typenum::{U3, U4};
    let vector3 = Vector::<usize, U3>::new(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    let vector4 = Vector::<usize, U4>::new(vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);
    // Can I make the default be Dynamic here?
    let vector4_dynamic = Vector::new(vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);

    add(&vector3, &vector4); // should fail to compile
    add(&vector3, &vector4_dynamic); // should fail at runtime
}
```

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/paholg/typenum/issues/67#issuecomment-256713503) in a typenum issue outlines how [nalgebra](https://crates.io/crates/nalgebra) accomplishes something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Specifying a default for type parameters](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/26870) has, sadly, still not been stabilized, so you'll need to use a nightly compiler in order for the following to work.

If you're playing with defaulted type parameters, be aware that the compiler will first try to infer the types based on usage, and only fall back to the default when there's not enough information. For example, if you were to pass a vector declared with an explicit `N` and a vector declared without `N` to `add`, the compiler would infer that the second vector's `N` must be the same as the first vector's `N`, instead of selecting `Dynamic` for the second vector's `N`. Therefore, if the sizes don't match, the runtime error would happen when constructing the second vector, not when adding them together.

---

It's possible to define multiple `impl` blocks for different sets of type parameters. For example, we can have an implementation of `new` when `N: Unsigned` and another when `N` is `Dynamic`.

```
extern crate typenum;

use std::marker::PhantomData;

use typenum::Unsigned;

struct Dynamic;

struct Vector<E, N> {
    vec: Vec<E>,
    _marker: PhantomData<N>,
}

impl<E, N: Unsigned> Vector<E, N> {
    fn new(vec: Vec<E>) -> Self {
        assert!(N::to_usize() == vec.len());
        Vector {
            vec: vec,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<E> Vector<E, Dynamic> {
    fn new(vec: Vec<E>) -> Self {
        Vector {
            vec: vec,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

However, this approach with two `impl`s providing a `new` method doesn't work well with defaulted type parameters; the compiler will complain about the ambiguity instead of inferring the default when calling `new`. So instead, we need to define a trait that unifies `N: Unsigned` and `Dynamic`. This trait will contain a method to help us perform the assert in `new` correctly depending on whether the size is fixed or dynamic.

```
#![feature(default_type_parameter_fallback)]

use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::ops::Add;

use typenum::Unsigned;

struct Dynamic;

trait FixedOrDynamic {
    fn is_valid_size(value: usize) -> bool;
}

impl<T: Unsigned> FixedOrDynamic for T {
    fn is_valid_size(value: usize) -> bool {
        Self::to_usize() == value
    }
}

impl FixedOrDynamic for Dynamic {
    fn is_valid_size(_value: usize) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

struct Vector<E, N: FixedOrDynamic = Dynamic> {
    vec: Vec<E>,
    _marker: PhantomData<N>,
}

impl<E, N: FixedOrDynamic> Vector<E, N> {
    fn new(vec: Vec<E>) -> Self {
        assert!(N::is_valid_size(vec.len()));
        Vector {
            vec: vec,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

---

In order to support `add` receiving a fixed and a dynamic vector, but not fixed vectors of different lengths, we need to introduce another trait. For each `N: Unsigned`, only `N` itself and `Dynamic` will implement the trait.

```
trait SameOrDynamic<N> {
    type Output: FixedOrDynamic;

    fn length_check(left_len: usize, right_len: usize) -> bool;
}

impl<N: Unsigned> SameOrDynamic<N> for N {
    type Output = N;

    fn length_check(_left_len: usize, _right_len: usize) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

impl<N: Unsigned> SameOrDynamic<Dynamic> for N {
    type Output = N;

    fn length_check(left_len: usize, right_len: usize) -> bool {
        left_len == right_len
    }
}

impl<N: Unsigned> SameOrDynamic<N> for Dynamic {
    type Output = N;

    fn length_check(left_len: usize, right_len: usize) -> bool {
        left_len == right_len
    }
}

impl SameOrDynamic<Dynamic> for Dynamic {
    type Output = Dynamic;

    fn length_check(left_len: usize, right_len: usize) -> bool {
        left_len == right_len
    }
}

fn add<E, N1, N2>(vector1: &Vector<E, N1>, vector2: &Vector<E, N2>) -> Vector<E, N2::Output>
    where N1: FixedOrDynamic,
          N2: FixedOrDynamic + SameOrDynamic<N1>,
{
    assert!(N2::length_check(vector1.vec.len(), vector2.vec.len()));
    unimplemented!()
}
```

If you don't actually need to support calling `add` with a fixed and a dynamic vector, then you can simplify this drastically:

```
fn add<E, N: FixedOrDynamic>(vector1: &Vector<E, N>, vector2: &Vector<E, N>) -> Vector<E, N> {
    // TODO: perform length check when N is Dynamic
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Comment: That last solution is surprisingly simple. Could I add a `Deref` implementation to coerce a `&Vector<E, N: Unsigned>` to `&Vector<E, N: Dynamic>` to get back the combined behavior for references or would that defeat the typed numbers by casting two mismatched `Unsigned` to `Dynamic`?

Comment: Adding such a `Deref` implementation doesn't work; the coercion doesn't kick in at all. I wouldn't recommend doing this anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could just keep using `Vec<T>` for what it does best, and use your `Vector<T, N>` for checked length vectors. To accomplish that, you can define a trait for addition and implement it for different combinations of the two types of vector:

```
trait MyAdd<T> {
    type Output;
    fn add(&self, other: &T) -> Self::Output;
}

impl <T, N: Unsigned> MyAdd<Vector<T, N>> for Vector<T, N> {
    type Output = Vector<T, N>;
    fn add(&self, other: &Vector<T, N>) -> Self::Output {
        Vector::new(/* implement addition here */)
    }
}

impl <T, N: Unsigned> MyAdd<Vec<T>> for Vector<T, N> {
    type Output = Vector<T, N>;
    fn add(&self, other: &Vec<T>) -> Self::Output {
        Vector::new(/* implement addition here */)
    }
}

impl <T> MyAdd<Vec<T>> for Vec<T> {
    type Output = Vec<T>;
    fn add(&self, other: &Vec<T>) -> Self::Output {
        Vec::new(/* implement addition here */)
    }
}

impl <T, N: Unsigned> MyAdd<Vector<T, N>> for Vec<T> {
    type Output = Vector<T, N>;
    fn add(&self, other: &Vector<T, N>) -> Self::Output {
        Vector::new(/* implement addition here */)
    }
}
```

Now you can use it almost in the same way as you were trying to:

```
fn main() {
    use typenum::{U3, U4};
    let vector3 = Vector::<usize, U3>::new(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    let vector4 = Vector::<usize, U4>::new(vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);
    let vector4_dynamic = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    vector3.add(&vector4); // Compile error!
    vector3.add(&vector4_dynamic); // Runtime error on length assertion
}
```

You could avoid creating your own trait by using the built in `std::ops::Add`, but you wouldn't be able to implement it for `Vec`. The left side of the `.add` would always have to be `Vector<E, N>` with `Vec` limited to only being in the argument. You could get around that with another `Vec` *"newtype"* wrapper, similar to what you've done with `Vector<E, T>` but without the length check and phantom type.

Comment: In my real case, my motivation for a dynamic type was so that I don't have to duplicate the algorithm (more complicated than `add`), but maybe I can abstract the algorithm into a private "unsafe" function that the typed functions call.

Comment: You can further simplify it by implementing `From<Vec<E>>` for`Vector<E, N>`, and then write your algorithm for any `V: Into<Vector<E, N>>`.

Comment: Actually I later realised that the suggestion from my last comment won't work. You can't implement `From<Vec<E>>` for `Vector<E, N>` because you'd need to know the length of the `Vec` at compile time, which defeats the point.